# Using COUNT and HAVING command to display only those department heads that have a count greater than 3

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The question is: Find the total number of employees working under each particular head of department (HOD). Display only those department heads that have a count greater than 3.

I have use COUNT to find out how many employees are under each Head Of Department (HOD) and then use HAVING to display the ones with count greater than 3.

Can anyone help me how can I create the syntax for the above question? I'm lost.

I started with the following, but I don't know what to do next.

SUBQUERY:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT HOD)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE HOD > 3;
```

Table:  EMPLOYEES

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME   JOB_ID  JOB_DESCRIPTION HOD HIREDATE    SALARY  DEPARTMENT_ID
       1           SMITH    J1      CLERK           5   17-Dec-07    5,800.00   20
       2           ALLEN    J2      SLAESMAN        3   20-Feb-08    7,600.00   30
       3            WARD    J2      SALESMAN        5   22-Feb-08    8,250.00   30
       4           JONES    J3      MANAGER         7   2-Apr-08     4,900.00   20
       5            JACK    J2      SALESMAN        7   28-Sep-08    6,700.00   10
       6           BLAKE    J3      MANAGER         7   1-May-08     12,850.00  30
       7           CLARK    J3      MANAGER        NULL 9-Jun-08     22,450.00  10  
       8           SCOTT    J4      ANALYST         5   9-Dec-08     13,000.00  20
       9          TURNER    J2      SALESMAN        3   8-Sep-07     5,500.00   30
      10           ADAMS    J1      CLERK           5   12-Jan-07    9,100.00   20
```

Comment: Is this hierarchical or are you just looking at direct reports?

Comment: You need to share some info about your table definitions to really get help.

Comment: all the attributes are under one table EMPLOYEES:

Comment: I posted the EMPLOYEES table.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the following answers the question you asked:

```
SELECT HOD, COUNT(*) AS EMPLOYEE_COUNT
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  GROUP BY HOD
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
  ORDER BY HOD;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02966/4)

Best of luck.